# If we should avoid foldl in Haskell, should we also avoid all helpers based on it?

Tags: performance, haskell, fold

Given (?) that `foldl'` is always preferred to `foldl`, does it mean that helpers like `maximum` which are based on `foldl` are also best avoided?

Should one rather use something like the [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) package to get efficient folds, and should this become common knowledge like usage of `foldl'`?

Comment: Fun fact: List.maximum is right-biased, while Foldl.maximum is left-biased in case of equality. I like the latter better, however can lead to surprises when migrating code. I would like this to be prominently documented.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't say that `foldl'` is better than `foldl`. It just happens that many uses of folds result in small structures and there the strictness is useful for avoiding excessive thunk creation and thus saving memory.

If you consider, for example, an application of `foldl'` that results in a list (e.g. `foldl' (++) []`), then you may still get thunks created, because the strictness is not [deep](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq).

```
Prelude Data.List> null (foldl' (++) [] [[0], undefined]])
False
```

On the other hand, if the result of your fold is an expansion of its input, making the fold strict can hamper performance. So in different circumstances different fold functions are useful.

Answer (score 4):

I think that's not really an issue, because in practice programs are built with optimization flags, which enable the strictness analyzer and most of simple `foldl`s essentially become `foldl'`s when possible. If there are real problems with memory consuming and leaking thunks, they should be detected and resolved via profiling, not premature suggestions.